# How do I return rows with a specific value first in fuel php?

Tags: php, sql, sql-order-by

I want complete sorting like this with MySQL FIELD function.

```
SELECT id, name, priority
FROM mytable
ORDER BY FIELD(priority, "core")
```

but how can I do in fuel php ? query builder ?

Comment: I don't quite understand your question. Can you show some data results? A sample data of what you're pulling from, what your query returns and what your desired results are?